# laravel condition of user type on login

Tags: laravel, redirect

I want to make condition on login. The system will have different types of users.

> Example: admin, manager, user.

I have tried all solutions given but it redirects the user to the same page.

> Database: Table - users : column: role.

The condition will be based on the role when they register.

Here is my code:

Logincontroller.php

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

  $this->redirectTo = '/dashboard';

  $user = \Auth::user();
  if ( ($role->admin() ) {
    // an admin
    $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
  } elseif ( ($role->manager() ) {
    // it's a manager
    $this->redirectTo = '/manager/home';
  }
  else {
    // it's a user
    $this->redirectTo = '/dashboard';
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to check if the user has a specific role. Now you are checking the role but not from a user. I would suggest doing something  like `$user->role->admin()`, can you maybe show some more code of the registercontroller?

Comment: Can you show me the file where you  specify the `admin(), manager()` functions

Comment: Tried before but it doesnt work. The registercontroller have default code, the only thing i add in both validator and create are the position: validator -  'position' => 'required|string|max:255',
 create -  'position' => $data['position'],

Comment: I only specify it in the database column position. I'm new with laravel.

Comment: You are trying to check a users role before the user is loggedin this will not work. You should do this after a user is loggedin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the redirect logic in the constructor because it will be called before the user authentication is even attempted, therefore it will always be "/dashboard".

You could add the `authenticated()` method to your `LoginController`, this method will be run after the user was successfully authenticated.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if ($user->admin()) {
        // an admin
        $redirect = '/admin';
    } elseif ($user->manager()) {
        // it's a manager
        $redirect = '/manager/home';
    } else {
        // it's a user
        $redirect = '/dashboard';
    }
    return redirect($redirect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for custom middleware for authentication and filtering user

[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware)

register in kernel and then apply your logic in middleware handle function

And as per your logic ,kindly confirm if you are checking your role properly because this may cause it end up in else condition.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making an `isAdmin()` and `isManager()`in the user model.
Do something like this:

In `App\User.php`

```
const ADMIN_TYPE = 'admin';
const MANAGER_TYPE = 'manager';

public function isAdmin() {
     return $this->role === self::ADMIN_TYPE;
 }

public function isManager() {
     return $this->role === self::MANAGER_TYPE;
}
```

In the `LoginController`

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected function authenticated() {

     if (auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
     // an admin
         $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the solutions. After trying your code i modify a bit and get the solutions (but might occur problem later).

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{
if($user->position = 'manager') {
    // change the redirectTo variable as needed
    $this->redirectTo = ('/manager/home');
} 
else //($user->position = 'admin')
{
    // change the redirectTo variable as needed
    $this->redirectTo = ('/admin/dashboard');
}
 return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```